# How can I use user entered text as a filename in Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to let the user enter a filename and use that text as the filename of the file that has to be uploaded to a GCS bucket.
This is what my code looks like:

```
user_input = str(st.text_input("Name your file: "))

sweep_string = "_exponential_sweep_.wav"
inv_filter_string = "_inverse_filter_.wav"
ir_string = "_impulse_response_.wav"

if user_input:

    wavfile.write(os.path.join(audio_files_path,
                               user_input + sweep_string), sample_rate, sweep)
    wavfile.write(os.path.join(audio_files_path,
                               user_input + inv_filter_string), sample_rate, inverse)
    wavfile.write(os.path.join(audio_files_path,
                               user_input + ir_string), sample_rate, ir)
```

I tried to add the two strings together in a variable before the wavfile.write but nothing changes. If I remove user_input from the wavefile.write it works, but I need the user to be able to name the files.

******* EDIT *******

Editing the question as a solution was proposed but it still does not work. Here's a longer extract of the code I'm using:

```
def select_sweep_time():
    sweep_duration_option = st.selectbox('Select the duration of the sweep',
                                         ('3s', '7s', '14s'))
    max_reverb_option = st.selectbox('Select the expected maximum reverb decay time',
                                     ('1s', '2s', '3s', '5s', '10s'))
    st.caption('''
        Note that longer sweeps provide more accuacy,
        but even short sweeps can be used to measure long decays
        ''')

    if sweep_duration_option == '3s':
        sweep_duration = 3
    elif sweep_duration_option == '7s':
        sweep_duration = 7
    elif sweep_duration_option == '14s':
        sweep_duration = 14

    if max_reverb_option == '1s':
        max_reverb_option = 1
    elif max_reverb_option == '2s':
        max_reverb_option = 2
    elif max_reverb_option == '3s':
        max_reverb_option = 3
    elif max_reverb_option == '5s':
        max_reverb_option = 5
    elif max_reverb_option == '10s':
        max_reverb_option = 10

    return sweep_duration_option, max_reverb_option

def write_wav_file(file_name, rate, data):
    audio_files_path = r'data/audio_files'
    """Write wav file base on input"""
    save_file_path = os.path.join(audio_files_path, file_name)

    wavfile.write(save_file_path, rate, data)
    st.success(
        f"File successfully written to audio_files_path as:>> {file_name}")

def sweep_save():
    if st.button("Play"):
        sweep = generate_exponential_sweep(sweep_duration, sample_rate)
        inverse = generate_inverse_filter(
            sweep_duration, sample_rate, sweep)
        ir = deconvolve(sweep, inverse)

        user_input = str(st.text_input("Name your file: "))

        if user_input:
            sweep_string = user_input + "_exponential_sweep_.wav"
            inv_filter_string = user_input + "_inverse_filter_.wav"
            ir_string = user_input + "_impulse_response_.wav"

            write_wav_file(file_name=sweep_string,
                           rate=sample_rate, data=sweep)

            write_wav_file(file_name=inv_filter_string,
                           rate=sample_rate, data=inverse)

            write_wav_file(file_name=ir_string, rate=sample_rate, data=ir)

def irm_tab():
    tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7, tab8, tab9 = st.tabs(
        ["Impulse",
         "ETC",
         "Schroeder Integral",
         "EDT",
         "T20",
         "T30",
         "Clarity C50",
         "Clarity C80",
         "FFT"]
    )

    with tab1:
        st.header("Impulse")
        st.markdown(
            """
            The impulse plot shows the decay of the IR visually.
            """
        )

        select_sweep_time()
        sweep_save()
```

The `irm_tab()` function is then called in a page file as per the multi-page setup displayed on the streamlit docs:

```
import streamlit as st
from utils import head_impulse_response, irm_tab


head_impulse_response()
irm_tab()
```

I don't know why but this method, even if correct in theory, does not work. If I remove `if user_input:` then it does work, but obviously it only saves the files with the default name, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a file name to the path before you write, I will recommend a function to take care of this task. Also you can just `st.text_input()` instead of `str(st.text_input())` because `text_input` returns a string.

```py
import streamlit as st
import os


def write_wav_file(file_name, rate, data):
    """Write wav file base on input"""
    audio_files_path = "/audio_files_path/here"
    save_file_path = os.path.join(audio_files_path, file_name)
    
    wavfile.write(save_file_path, rate, data)
    st.success(f"File successfully written to audio_files_path as:>> {file_name}")
    

user_input = st.text_input("Name your file: ")

if user_input:
    sweep_string = user_input + "_exponential_sweep_.wav"
    inv_filter_string = user_input + "_inverse_filter_.wav"
    ir_string = user_input + "_impulse_response_.wav"
    
    write_wav_file(file_name=sweep_string, rate=sample_rate, data=sweep)
    
    write_wav_file(file_name=inv_filter_string, rate=sample_rate, data=inverse)
    
    write_wav_file(file_name=ir_string, rate=sample_rate, data=ir)
```

***Edition:***
Now we can see that the problem is caused by `if st.button("Play"):` in your `sweep_save():`. Streamlit button has no **callback**, that means whenever a user makes any entry under a button, the page will reload and the data will be lost. In order to handle such problem, you will have to initialize a session state for the button.

I add few lines of code to your `sweep_save():` to initialize the button

```py
def sweep_save():
    playbtn = st.button("Play")
    if "playbtn_state" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.playbtn_state = False

    if playbtn or st.session_state.playbtn_state:
        st.session_state.playbtn_state = True
    
        sweep = generate_exponential_sweep(sweep_duration, sample_rate)
        ...
```

I think this should resolve the problem now.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Sadly this still does not work. I'll paste a more complete version of my code, maybe I have some errors somewhere:
``

Comment: If I set the condition "if user_input" the files are not created, even if I remove the string addition. The two functions are called inside streamlit tabs, but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: When you enter the name in streamlit, hit the **enter** key, if your code works properly, this code should work too.

Comment: Yes of course, but it does not work. I know that the file path is correct because without the user_input condition the files are created and saved. On the streamlit docs I've seen that st.text_input returns a string, but on the website the examples show that the string is accessed with st.write. I'm now wondering if the string is only accessible through streamlit

Comment: That  is not the problem, How do you write without `st.text_input`?

Comment: I'm using `st.text_input` only to let the user type the filename of the file before saving it to the GCS bucket. I need this so that the user could later retrieve the file by searching it with keywords.

Comment: I understand. You said the code works without `st.text_input` so how does the code look like without `st.text_input`? I think you will have to update your question, that might help to resolve the error.

Comment: I updated the question as requested. Anyway, it works if I "skip" `st.text_input`by removing the ìf user_input`condition. This way the user_input is not registered and therefore only "_exponential_sweep_.wav" (for example) is used as the filename.

Comment: That was cased by the `st.button("Play")` so  I edited the answer by adding some code to the `sweep_save():`

Comment: It was a pleasure @EttoreCarlessi and I am glad that it worked! Have a good day!